# Redundancy when reading USB serial port (C;Mac OSX;Arduino)

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

I'm writing a simple C program that can read data from a USB port that is connected to my Arduino device. The Arduino outputs data at a baud rate of 9600 in chunks of 4 bytes.

I want the input from the Arduino to my computer to look something like this:

136.134.132.130.129.127.126.124.121.119.117.115.113.111.

However, I'm getting something like this:

271.274.281..2.4062.4022.40225.4021

Question: How do I get the input in my C program to neatly synchronize with out loosing data/ rereading data? Are there some kind of flags that could tell my program when the port has new data?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/types.h>


int open_port(void)
{
  int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

  fd = open("/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/tty");
  }
  else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

  struct termios options;
  tcgetattr(fd,&options);
  cfsetospeed(&options,B9600);
  options.c_cflag |=(CLOCAL | CREAD);
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

  return (fd);
}


int main (){

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){

    fcntl(open_port(), F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    char buf[5];
    size_t nbytes;
    ssize_t bytes_read;

    nbytes = sizeof(buf);
    bytes_read = read(open_port(), buf, nbytes);
    printf("%s ", buf);
    buf[0]=0;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program does not properly **open()** the serial port for reading it.
In fact it repeatedly opens it two times every iteration of the **for** loop.
The device should be opened only once by your program.

Instead of

```
for (i=0; i<50; i++) {

   fcntl(open_port(), F_SETFL, FNDELAY);

   bytes_read = read(open_port(), buf, nbytes);

}
```

the main program should be structured like

```
fd = open_port();
if (fd < 0) {
    /* handle error condition */
}
rc = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
if (rc < 0) {
    /* handle error condition */
}
for (i=0; i<50; i++) {


   bytes_read = read(fd, buf, nbytes);
   if (bytes_read < 0) {
        /* handle error condition */
    }

}
close(fd);
```

Your program is too "simple".  It sets only a few attributes, and doesn't bother to check the return codes of system calls.

Is this supposed to be canonical or non-canonical (aka raw) mode (i.e. is the data ASCII text or binary)?
Refer to this [Serial Programming Guide](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) for proper setup of the serial port.

> read data from a USB port

USB is a bus.
The device your program reads from is a serial port attached to that USBus.

**Second coding issue**

Your original code may print garbage data.

```
nbytes = sizeof(buf);
bytes_read = read(open_port(), buf, nbytes);
printf("%s ", buf);
buf[0]=0;
```

The bytes returned by the **read()** operation are not likely to be terminated by a NULL byte, so a string operation on that read buffer could exceed the bounds of the allocated array.
Code that would not misbehave would be something like:

```
nbytes = sizeof(buf) - 1;

bytes_read = read(fd, buf, nbytes);
if (bytes_read < 0) {
    /* handle error condition */
} else {
    buf[bytes_read] = 0; /* append terminator */
    printf("%s ", buf);
}
```

Note that **nbytes** is one less than the allocated size of the buffer.
This is to ensure that there is an available byte to store the string terminator byte when the **read()** operation returns a "full" buffer of **nbytes**.
For efficiency the assignment of **nbytes** should be performed before entering the **for** loop, rather than within the loop.

Comment: I must confess, I believe that this site is full of magicians. Very informative post. The input is coming in now how I hoped it would (with the exception of one minor glitch) Thank You!